# In Scheme what's the difference between a number and an object?

Tags: lisp

If in Scheme I have something like:

`one = 1`

and the number 1. What would the difference be between these two, the symbol one and the number 1? Isn't the number 1 also a symbol (for the number 1)? And what about things like Pi, or e? Are they numbers or symbols?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean `(define one 1)` rather than `one = 1`.

In this context, `one` is an identifier (and not a symbol). An identifier refers to a value, and in this case, the `one` identifier has the value 1. (Numbers are not symbols or identifiers, by the way.) But it does not always have to be the case. Consider the following:

```
(define one 1)
(define (my-function one)
  (display one))

(my-function 42)
```

Although `my-function` contains the expression `(display one)`, the expression `(my-function 42)` will actually print 42, because the `one` here refers to `my-function`'s parameter, not to the top-level `one`.

`pi` and `e` are also identifiers, and can be bound to any value. You can, of course, use the following definitions to give them the values you're expecting:

```
(define pi (acos -1))
(define e (exp 1))
```